# String replace() in java

Tags: java

We have a

```
String s="my name is bob";
System.out.print(s.replace("a","p"));   // so here a replace to p
```

but I want a variable in the place of a

example

```
char o='a';
system.out.print(s.replace(o,"p"));
```

But here it is giving an error so how can be put a variable inside a replace method is there any way to do it?

Comment: `String o="a";`

Comment: Make o a String

Comment: or `system.out.print(s.replace(o,'p'));` if you want to replace a single `char` with a single `char`.

Comment: Because there is no such method. The `.replace()` has two signatures, one of which is `replace(char,char)` and second is `replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`.

Comment: Please look carefully at your code. In your first example you use a String for `"a"` but in your second example you define it as `char`.

Answer (score 2):

The two variables you give to `String.replace` have to be the same value (`""`). This means what's in is a string so you have to change `"p"` to `'p'`
or change `char o = 'a'` to `String o = "a"`.

Answer (score 1):

String replace takes two chars as its input and replaces the old with the new. For your example you'd need to make the p a char.

```
String s="my name is bob";
System.out.print(s.replace('a','p'));
//Result - my npme is bob
```

Comment: I already mention it in my question then also thank you for your time I got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Change char o to String o

Replace is expecting string parameters
Also try using replaceAll() if you what to replace all these characters, not just the first one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no suitable method found for replace(char,String)

Try this:

```
String s="my name is bob";

String o="a";
System.out.print(s.replace(o,"p"));
```

Comment: yes thankyou for your solution the first argument . should be a string type only

Answer (score 0):

Guys I found it by my self just check the answer

```
public class HelloWorld    
{               
     public static void main(String []args){

     String s="my name is aman shrivastava";
       String p = "a";
        System.out.println(s.replace(p,"s"));

        //or

        char e='a';
        String ps=Character.toString(e);
        System.out.println(s.replace(ps,""));        

       System.out.println(s);                      
     }
}
```